# Google Apps Admin Settings API - 401

Tags: asp.net, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-oauth

I'm trying to get the Organization name for a Google Apps domain. For this, I'm using the Google Apps Admin Settings API. I saw that it required 3-Legged OAuth. I try to implement OAuth 2.0 because OAuth 1 is deprecated. I try many thing to get this work but I'm always getting a 401 unautorized.

I request a token for the scope : https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/

Here is my code:

```
// ClientID & ClientSecret values
var requestFactory = GDAPI.GoogleApps.GetAuthRequestFactory();

string organizationName = String.Empty;

 Google.GData.Apps.AdminSettings.AdminSettingsService service = 
            new Google.GData.Apps.AdminSettings.AdminSettingsService(auth.Domain, Excendia.Mobility.Utilities1.BLL.WebConfig.ExcendiaAppName);
 service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
 service.SetAuthenticationToken(token);

 try
 {
     var result = service.GetOrganizationName(); // throw exception here...
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     log.Error(ex);
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Is this compatible with OAuth 2?

I also want to ask if there is another way to get organization name because GData library is supposed to be obsolete and replaced by new Google.Apis...

**Resolved!**

Thanks Jay. It works on OAuth 2.0 playground. Something on my side was not set correctly.

Using Fiddler I saw the Authorization header being set by my application. It was set to OAuth v1 instead of v2. So I found out I was using the wrong RequestFactory class.
Need to use GOAuth2RequestFactory instead of GOAuthRequestFactory...

So this is now working:

```
string organizationName = String.Empty;

Google.GData.Apps.AdminSettings.AdminSettingsService service = 
            new Google.GData.Apps.AdminSettings.AdminSettingsService(auth.Domain, "myAppName");

service.RequestFactory = 
            new Google.GData.Client.GOAuth2RequestFactory("cl", "MyAppName",
            new Google.GData.Client.OAuth2Parameters()
            { ClientId = ClientID, 
              ClientSecret = ClientSecret, 
              AccessToken = token });

try
{

    var result = service.GetOrganizationName();

    if (result != null)
    {
        organizationName = result.OrganizationName;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error(ex);
}

return organizationName;
```

Comment: Have you registered your app for that particular scope? You cannot ask for access tokens for scope that your app isn't registered for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the correct API. Though GData is being replaced by the new Google APIs, Admin Settings API still uses the old GData format for now.

Are you using a super administrator account to authenticate with? Can you try the operation on the [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and see if it works for the account there?

You can also take a look at how [Dito GAM](http://www.ditoweb.com/dito-gam), an open source Google Apps tool implements [this call](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/DomainSettingsExamples#Retrieving_Domain_Settings). If you create a file named debug.gam in the same path as GAM, GAM will print out all the raw HTTP calls and responses it's making/getting.

Comment: Thanks. OAuth 2.0 playground help me to validate my request and yes I had super admin rights.